# what's the meaning of 'parameterize' in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning

[no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfJfN.jpg)
[13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfJfN.jpg)

what's the meaning of 'parameterize' in deep learning? As shown in the photo, does it means the matrix 'A' can be changed by the optimization during training?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when something can be parameterized it means that gradients can be calculated.

This means that the (dE/dw) which means the derivative of Error with respect to weight can be calculated (i.e it must be differentiable) and subtracted from the model weights along with obviously a learning_rate and other params being included depending on the optimizer.

What the paper is saying is that if you make a binary matrix a weight and then find the gradient (dE/dw) of that weight with respect to a loss and then make an update on the binary matrix through backpropagation, there is not really an **activation function** (which by requirement must be differentiable) that can keep the values discrete (like 0 and 1) but rather you will end up with continous values (like these decimal values).

Therefore it is saying since the idea of having binary values be weights and for them to be back-propagated in a way where the weights + activation function also yields an updated weight matrix that is also binary is difficult, another solution like the Bernoulli Distribution is used instead to initialize parameters of a model.

Hope this helps,